# Click on marker on map to show 2 ggplot chart on R shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, leaflet, marker

I am new to R shiny. 
I am able to show 1 line chart upon clicking on the marker on the map. However, I would like to show 2 line charts together, one on top of another at the side of the map, upon clicking onto the marker on the map. 
I have attached the code below for 2 line charts. 
Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

```
library(shiny)    # for shiny apps
library(leaflet)  # renderLeaflet function
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)

server = function(input, output) {


  Cookedfood_R <- readRDS("~/hawkermaster.rds")
  line <- readRDS("~/line.rds")
  line2 <- readRDS("~/line2.rds")

  #Reshape the data for ggplot
  traff2 <- melt(line,id=c("TYPE","newname"),variable.name = "Year")
  traff3 <- melt(line2,id=c("TYPE","newname"),variable.name = "Year")

  #Remove the X in the Year column and convert it to number
  traff2$Year <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern="X",replacement = "",x = as.character(traff2$Year)))
  traff3$Year <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern="X",replacement = "",x = as.character(traff3$Year)))


  #getColor <- function(Cookedfood_R) { 
  #  sapply(Cookedfood_R$TYPE, function(TYPE) { 
  #    if(TYPE == 1) {"blue"} 
  #    else {"orange"} }) 
  #} 
  icons <- awesomeIcons( 
    icon = 'ion-close', 
    iconColor = 'black', 
    library = 'ion', 
    markerColor = getColor(Cookedfood_R) 
  ) 

  output$map = renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(data = Cookedfood_R,  
                 lat = ~ LATITUDE,  
                 lng = ~ LONGITUDE, 
                 icon = icons, 
                 layerId =~HAWKER,
                 popup = paste(Cookedfood_R$HAWKER, "<br>",
                               "No. of cooked food stalls:", Cookedfood_R$Cook, "<br>",
                               "No. of Market stalls:", Cookedfood_R$market,"<br>"))})


  # generate data in reactive
  ggplot_data <- reactive({
    site <- input$map_marker_click$id
    traff2[traff2$newname %in% site,]
  })

  ggplot_data2 <- reactive({
    site2 <- input$map_marker_click$id2
    traff3[traff3$newname %in% site2,]
  })

 output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = ggplot_data(), aes(x = Year, y = value, color = TYPE))+
      geom_line()+theme_bw()
      #geom_point(aes(shape=TYPE, size=1))
 })   
   output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
     ggplot(data = ggplot_data2(), aes(x = Year, y = value, color = TYPE))+
       geom_line()+theme_bw()
     #geom_point(aes(shape=TYPE, size=1))
  }) 
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  column(8,leafletOutput("map", height="700px")),
  column(4,br(),br(),br(),br(),plotOutput("plot1", height="300px")),
  column(4,br(),br(),br(),br(),plotOutput("plot2", height="300px")),
  br()
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to test your code without test data but this line is incorrect:

```
site2 <- input$map_marker_click$id2
```

Each marker click updates `input$map_marker_click$id` - there is no `id2`.

If I understand your code correctly in that one marker click should show 2 line charts then changing to:

```
site2 <- input$map_marker_click$id
```

might work. If not, let me know more details and/or please give us some dummy data to work with.

Comment: After reading again I might be misunderstanding your question completely, sorry.